# What's the difference between query(#idname).innerHTML and query(#idname).text

Tags: dart

my function look like this:

```
 void write (String message) {
    query("#status").innerHTML = message;
    query("#head").text = "Click me!";

  }
```

all of them catch id and show text to web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general browser document model, `innerHtml` refers to all the internal HTML, whereas `text` just refers to the text values of the elements. innerHtml is often used by dhtml and Ajax to change a div, where text would be just to set the text value of a single element.

This is more explicitly illustrated when getting, rather than setting, i.e.

e.g. Given:

```
<div id="idName">
    Text in the Div
    <p id="anotherId">Inner P</p>
</div>
```

**innerHtml** returns

```
Text in the Div 
<p id="anotherId">Inner P</p>
```

**text** returns :

```
Text in the Div 
Inner P
```

Comment: i try your code, but query("#idName").innerHTML; and query("#idName").text; all of them return look like your text returns. Sorry if i don't understand your answer :)

Comment: Maybe try this:  
    #import('dart:html');
    void main() {
      Element el = new Element.html('<i>foo<b>bar</b></i>');
      document.body.nodes.add(el);
      print(el.innerHTML);
      print(el.text);
    }  
  
Should print different things for text & innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
String message = """<form method="get" action="#ref"><input name="first_name"/></p><input     type="submit" value="Send"/></form>""";
write (message);
```

then you will appreciate the difference.
The innerHTML should operate an injection of code (an html form in the example) into the HTML page.

Comment: on a DIV element precisely.